# Is the limit$~ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{nx}}=0~$?

Tags: calculus

Is the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{nx}}$ equal to zero?

I found so by "common sense", I guess. Is there a way to do it and show the instructor? Factorization possibly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your "common sense" approach is here?  How exactly did you come to the conclusion that the limit should be zero?

Comment: Also, this limit actually seems a bit strange.  Should that be a limit as $n \to \infty$ (which is what you have written) or a limit as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: For negative x, the limit may not be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit being equal to $0$ or not existing, depends on the value of $x$. Note you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{nx}} & = \lim_{n \to \infty} x\left(\frac{x^{n}}{e^{nx}}\right) \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} x\left(\frac{x}{e^{x}}\right)^n
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If $\left|\frac{x}{e^x}\right| \lt 1$, then the limit becomes $0$. Note you will never have $\frac{x}{e^x} \ge 1$ since for it to be positive, since $e^x \gt 0$, requires $x \gt 0$, but then $e^x \gt x$ (e.g., from $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots$), so $\frac{x}{e^x} \lt 1$. Finally, if $\frac{x}{e^x} \le -1$, there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n= \frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{nx}}\implies \log(a_n)=(n+1)\log(x)-nx=-n(x-\log(x))+\log(x)$$ and $\forall x>0 \,\,\, x>\log(x)$